# Performing an operation straight after loading a new document

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I'm trying to perform a delete file operation straight after i load a new document. Is this possible? I tried:

```
BOOL CEmergenceDoc::OnNewDocument()  
{
    if (!CRichEditDoc::OnNewDocument())
        return FALSE;

CString title = CEmergenceView::GetView()->GetDoc()->GetTitle();

CStringA sB(title);
    const char* pszC = sB;
    char* pszD = const_cast<char*>(pszC);

    if(std::ifstream(pszD) ) {
        CEmergenceDoc::isNewFile = false;
    DeleteFile(title);
}

    return TRUE;
  }
```

but this gives me a debug assertion error.

EDIT:

After a bit more digging I've discovered that the debug assertion error is being displayed because I am calling the view before the view has been loaded. But then where can I put this code so that it executes straight after a new document and view has been loaded?

Answer (score 1):

If you really need the view then you can use [`CView::OnInitialUpdate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xc7fw3a0.aspx).

I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do but I would question whether you actually need the view. Can't you just do:

```
 CString title = GetTitle();
```

assuming that `CEmergenceDoc` derives from `CDocument`. Or are you trying to get the document title from the currently displayed view for another document?

Comment: I tried ovverriding CView::OnIntitialUpdate()....but it is still giving me a debug assertion error.

Comment: You're going to have to show more code as I can only guess what you are doing. Best bet is to reduce the code to a minimal example that reproduces the issue. Chances are you'll be able to find and fix the issue but if not you have a good small code snippet for another SO question.

Comment: Again. Don't go via the view. The GetTitle is available form the current document you are in!